# EACCES: permission denied, unlink

Tags: reactjs

I can't launched my project with react.js with command `yarn install`.
Get error:

```
error /Users/lera/Desktop/beam-web/node_modules/sharp: 
Failed to auto-install node-gyp. Please run "yarn global add node-gyp" manually. 
Error: "EACCES: permission denied, 
unlink '/Users/lera/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/.yarn-integrity'"
```

npm 5.0.3.
node 8.1.4.
yarn 0.24.5
macOS Sierra 10.12.4

When I launched command again it installs packages, but after command `yarn run dev`it shows following:

```
Cannot find module '../build/Release/sharp.node'
```

I tried to add sharp by `yarn add sharp`, but receive the same error. EACCES: permission denied

Comment: What is the output of `ls -la /Users/lera/Desktop/beam-web/` and `whoami` ?

Comment: @msanford ls -la /Users/lera/Desktop/beam-web/ - shows structure of my project.
whoami - lera.

Comment: I'm sure it shows the structure of your project, what I want to know is what the output of the third column is. Does it match your username for every entry, especially `node_modules`?

Comment: @msanford yes, it is matched.

Comment: @msanford yes for node_modules too.

Comment: @msanford oh stop! third column is staff!

Comment: And what are the permissions on your `node_modules` folder? Can you edit your question and just paste the output of `ls -la /Users/lera/Desktop/beam-web/ | grep node_modules` please? It will save extended discussion in comments :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149479/discussion-between-valeria-shpiner-and-msanford).

Comment: same error here im getting `EACCESS permission denied unlink /project/node_modules/.bin/_mocha` users are same

Comment: @SlimShady do you need help? We solved this problem.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

First of all, you need to check permission by running the command:

```
ls -la ~/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/.yarn*
```

I received the next response:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root staff 15163 Jul 18 15:17 ~/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/.yarn-integrity
```

Then if you saw that **root** had permission, but you don't have, you should **add permission to yourself**:

```
sudo chown -R ${USER} ~/.config/yarn/
```

Answer (score 4):

Change permissions for files, folders, or disks on Mac
Permission settings determine who can view and alter files on the computer. You change permission settings at the bottom of the Info window for a file, folder, or disk in the Finder. For example, you can change permission settings for a folder so that other users who log in to your Mac, or connect to it for file sharing, can view but not change files in a folder.

The permission settings at the bottom of an Info window.
Assign permissions to users and groups
On your Mac, select a disk, folder, or file, then choose File > Get Info.

If the information in Sharing & Permissions isn’t visible, click the arrow .

If the lock at the bottom right is locked , click it to unlock the Get Info options, then enter an administrator name and password.

Click a user or group in the Name column, then choose a privilege setting from the pop-up menu.

Read & Write: Allows a user to open the item and change it.

Read only: Allows a user to open the item, but not change its contents.

Write only (Drop Box): Makes a folder into a drop box. Users can copy items to the drop box, but can’t open it. Only the owner of the drop box can open it.

No Access: Blocks all access to the item.

You can undo any changes to privilege settings for a user or group in the Sharing & Permissions section since opening the Info window. Before closing the Info window, click the Action pop-up menu , then choose “Revert changes.”

Apply permissions to all items in a folder or a disk
On your Mac, select a folder or disk, then choose File > Get Info.

If the lock at the bottom right is locked , click it to unlock the Get Info options, then enter an administrator name and password.

Click the Action pop-up menu , then choose “Apply to enclosed items.”

Change an item’s owner
On your Mac, select the item, then choose File > Get Info.

If the lock at the bottom right is locked , click it to unlock the Get Info options, then enter an administrator name and password.

If the new owner’s name isn’t listed in the Name column in the Sharing & Permissions section, click the Add button  to add the new owner.

Select the new owner in the Name column, click the Action pop-up menu , then choose “Make __ the owner.”

You can undo any changes to an item’s owner in the Sharing & Permissions section since opening the Info window. Before closing the Info window, click the Action pop-up menu , then choose “Revert changes.”

Add or remove a user or group in the Name column
On your Mac, select an item, then choose File > Get Info.

If the lock at the bottom right is locked , click it to unlock the Get Info options, then enter an administrator name and password.

In the Sharing & Permissions section, do any of the following:

Add a user or group: Click the Add button  below the list, select a user or group, then click Select.

Remove a user or group: Select the user or group, then click the Remove button  below the list.

You can undo adding or removing a user or group in the Sharing & Permissions section since opening the Info window. Before closing the Info window, click the Action pop-up menu , then choose “Revert changes.”[image]

Answer (score 3):

I tried with **sudo yarn** to get privilege. Its worked for me.

try **sudo yarn** instead **yarn install**.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the permission of the specific file or simply running the `install` command with `sudo` might seem like a quick fix, but let's delve into why this issue might be occurring and how to address it:

Ideally, you shouldn't require administrative privileges for a straightforward `yarn install`. The reason this situation arises is likely due to the presence of certain files generated with **root** (admin) **level permissions**. This typically happens when you've attempted to execute a command with `sudo`.

If you find yourself in such a situation, the most straightforward solution is to start afresh:

- Run `sudo git clean -fdx` to eliminate all untracked files. The necessity of using sudo here comes from the fact that you need administrative-level access to delete files with similar privileges.
- Next, run `yarn install`

This should help resolve the issue without resorting to elevated privileges.

Answer (score -2):

check first that you're in the same directory as your package.json file, you'll get that error if you're on a different directory...