# yarn install: EACCES: permission denied, unlink yarn integrity

Tags: linux, npm, permissions, yarnpkg

yarn install throws:

```
EACCES: permission denied, unlink '/home/minnak/Darbas/market/node_modules/.yarn-integrity'
```

Might be related to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45166318/eacces-permission-denied-unlink)

I tried checking for permissions:

```
ls -la /home/minnak/Darbas/market/node_modules/.yarn*
```

Output: `-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 490276 kov.  13 15:10 /home/minnak/Darbas/market/node_modules/.yarn-integrity`

and then:

```
sudo chown -R minnak /home/minnak/.config/yarn/
```

Then launch yarn install again and get the same error.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try running `sudo rm -rf /home/minnak/Darbas/market/node_modules/` and then `yarn` without elevated permissions.

Comment: This works but I keep having to do it a lot. I have 3 projects in my workspace and I have to do it for each one all the time.

Comment: I did something similar but less destructive, from the project folder: `sudo chown -R $USER:$GROUP node_modules`